# Swift: Firebase read permission denied

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

So I'm building this app in swift, which has data that should be read before user logging in.

To secure it from being read from out of my app, I put up the basic security rule:

```
".read": "auth != null"
```

To prevent read before logging in, I put up a loading view controller while calling:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let ref = Firebase(url: "<my firebase url>")

    ref.observeAuthEventWithBlock({ authData in
        if authData != nil {
            segueToListViewController()
        }
    })
    return true
}
```

But when I get to such point, sometimes firebase gives me "permission denied" error, sometimes it doesn't.

I'm sure there's a logged user, because I'm logging everything:

- Login changed
- User logged in AuthData facebook:
- applicationDidBecomeActive
- Loaded ListViewController
- Loading Data
- Error: Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission Denied"

So why does Firebase sometimes denies reading when the user is logged in?

Comment: What thread are you on when that block runs? You can set a breakpoint or use `NSThread.isMainThread()`

Comment: I tried that, tried wrapping the block call in `            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { })`, and tried clearing all possible listeners that existed by that point with no success.
Seems like something in memory is ruining it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty late to this party, but it might help if you put the .read rule one level higher, directly under the child's name.

For example

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid", 
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },
    "child": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null", 
      "$child": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```